# Three.js/GLSL - Convert Pixel Coordinate to World Coordinate

Tags: three.js, glsl, webgl, glsles

I have a simple shader in my Three.js application that colors the screen red. However, I want to color all pixels to the right of a given world position to to a different color.

I have seen [some](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4899606/1138263) [answers](http://www.gamedev.net/topic/498615-how-can-i-get-the-world-coordinates-in-a-glsl-pixel-shader-by-using-the-depth-value/) that suggest using `varying vec4 worldCoord = gl_ModelViewMatrix * gl_Vertex;`, but since WebGL using GLSLES, variables like gl_Vertex are not available to me.

---

**Vertex Shader**

```
<script type="x-shader/x-vertex" id="vertexshader">
    #ifdef GL_ES
    precision highp float;
    #endif

    void main()
    {
        gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4(position,1.0);
    }
</script>
```

---

**Fragment Shader**

```
<script type="x-shader/x-fragment" id="fragmentshader">
    #ifdef GL_ES
    precision highp float;
    #endif

    float worldX = 10.0; //Or some other position in the WebGL world

    void main()
    {
        if(gl_FragCoord.x > worldX) //FragCoord gives me coordinates relative to the screen
        {
            gl_FragColor = vec4(0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1);
        }

        else
        {
            gl_FragColor = vec4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1);
        }
    }
</script>
```

---

**Q: How do I convert the position of a pixel to it's world position in WebGL using Three.js?**

---

Comment: See if this helps you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19776554/three-js-a-vertex-shader-to-color-based-on-location-of-pixel-on-screen/19781424#19781424

Comment: @WestLangley: Your first Fiddle on the question is closer to what I'm looking to accomplish. I was able to derive the solution from it. See my answer below. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer derived from WestLangley's Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/ST4aM/2/.

---

**Vertex Shader**

```
<script type="x-shader/x-vertex" id="vertexshader">
    #ifdef GL_ES
    precision highp float;
    #endif

    varying float x;
    varying float y;
    void main()
    {
        gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4(position,1.0);
        x = position.x;
        y = position.y;
    }
</script>
```

---

**Fragment Shader**

```
<script type="x-shader/x-fragment" id="fragmentshader">
    #ifdef GL_ES
    precision highp float;
    #endif

    varying float x;
    varying float y;

    void main()
    {
        if(x > somePosition)
        {
            gl_FragColor = vec4(0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1);
        }

        else
        {
            gl_FragColor = vec4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1);
        }
    }
</script>
```

---

Comment: That may be the answer you want but it is not an answer to the question you asked