# THREE.js/GLSL: WebGL shader to color fragments based on world space position

Tags: three.js, glsl, webgl, glsles

I have seen solution to color fragments based on their position in screen space or in their local object space like [Three.js/GLSL - Convert Pixel Coordinate to World Coordinate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20307489/three-js-glsl-convert-pixel-coordinate-to-world-coordinate?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Those are working with screen coordinates and do change when the camera moves or rotates; or only apply to local object space.

What I like to accomplish instead is to color fragments based on their `position` in world space (as in world space of the three.js scene graph).

Even when the camera moves the color should stay constant.

Example of wished behaviour: A 1x1x1 cube positioned in world space at (x:0,y:0,z:2) would have its third component (blue == z) always between 1.5 - 2.5. This should be true even if the camera moves.

What I have got so far:

*vertex shader*

```c
varying vec4 worldPosition;

void main() {


  // The following changes on camera movement:
  worldPosition = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4(position, 1.0);

  // This is closer to what I want (colors dont change when camera moves)
  // but it is in local not world space:
  worldPosition = vec4(position, 1.0);

  // This works fine as long as the camera doesnt move:
  worldPosition = modelViewMatrix * vec4(position, 1.0);
  // Instead I'd like the above behaviour but without color changes on camera movement


  gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4(position, 1.0);

}
```

*fragment shader*

```c
uniform vec2 u_resolution;
varying vec4 worldPosition;

void main(void)
{
    // I'd like to use worldPosition something like this:
    gl_FragColor = vec4(worldPosition.xyz * someScaling, 1.0);
    // Here this would mean that fragments xyz > 1.0 in world position would be white and black for <= 0.0; that would be fine because I can still divide it to compensate

}
```

Here is what I have got:
https://glitch.com/edit/#!/worldpositiontest?path=index.html:163:15

If you move with *wasd* you can see that the colors don't stay in place. I'd like them to, however.

Comment: You need values between 0 and 1 for colors so you need some way to convert your world coordinates. You use `fract(worldCoord.xyz * scale)` as one example

Comment: @gman I am aware of that, I edited the code part to indicate the scaling. But that doesn't answer the question, I am afraid, because I need to get the proper `worldPosition` in the first place (the position based on object positions in world space, that don't change on camera movement).

Comment: Have you tried `modelMatrix` as in `worldPosition = modelMatrix * vec4(position, 1);`? If three.js doesn't already make it for you you can make your own uniform and pass it in

Comment: @gman I have tried that (I suppose three.js's `modelViewMatrix` == `modelMatrix`), that is the behavior I want as long as the camera stays fixed. But once the camera moves, the colors change accordingly, which is not the effect I am looking for. A cube at a fixed position should keep its colors even if the camera moves.

Comment: @gman I stand corrected, you are right, as is @neeh in the answer below. I have mixed up `modelMatrix` and `modelViewMatrix`, using your suggestion works of course. Still working on comprehending the relationship between the different matrices.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your `worldPosition` is wrong. You shouldn't implicate the camera in the calculation. That means, no `projectionMatrix` nor `viewMatrix`.

```
// The world poisition of your vertex: NO CAMERA
vec4 worldPosition = modelMatrix * vec4(position, 1.0);

// Position in normalized screen coords: ADD CAMERA
gl_Position = projectionMatrix * viewMatrix * worldPosition;

// Here you can compute the color based on worldPosition, for example:
vColor = normalize(abs(worldPosition.xyz));
```

Check [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4nzkwesg/1/).

---

#### Note

Notice that the `abs()` used here for the color can potentially give the same color for different position, which might not be what you're looking for.

[image: Position coords to color coords]

Comment: Thank you! Apparently, and a bit embarassingly, I have mixed up `modelMatrix` and `modelViewMatrix`. I am still learning the concepts of OpenGL and this slipped through.